# Systems of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

If I have a system of N linear equations with N unknowns, how do I know if each unknown has atleast one solution. I havn't taken any formal classes in linear algebra, so please if you use any abstract terminology associated with linear algebra, explain it please. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: This is a useful method: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination

I don't think there is any simple way of going around linear algebra on a question like this (assuming that your N equations are of linear form).

Comment: I apologise I should have reworded my question better. I don't need help solving a system of linear equations, I want to know under what condinitions a system with n unknowns and n equations IS solveable. I am also not asking you to not use linear algebra, I am just asking you to explain any abstract notation, if you chose to use it.

Comment: Are we to assume these are linear equations? I think in general knowing in advance whether we can solve any set of $N$ equations in $N$ unknowns is very difficult, if not impossible. However if they are linear equations then there is a very simple test, calculate the determinant (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant). If it is non-zero (which is extremely likely) then you have a unique solution. If it is $0$ then you either have no solutions or infinitely many, and it is easy to check which is the case.

Comment: Yes all the equations are linear, and I don't even need unique solutions, I just need to know that all N unknowns have atleast one solution. Also I don't know what a "determinant" is, if you could help me out, id appreciate it.

Comment: no you can't always find solution, the coefficients must satisfy certain conditions

Comment: What conditions must they satisfy?

Comment: this is where matrices comes in. if one forms a matrix with the coefficients, the rows and columns must be linearly independent.

Comment: Im still fuzzy with linear algebra terminology, but when you say that two row/column vectors are linearly independent. That means none of their compoenents are scaled up versions of each other, right?

Comment: you're absolutely right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Take a look at [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/229632/31280) explaining where a certain matrix is proven to be non invertivible using a system of linear equations.
- Also read this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations#Properties) explaining the properties of a system of linear equations.